# Is there a way to end the program if statement is false?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am a just a beginner Java programmer and I was just wondering if there is a way to end the program if the user input is false. Here is an example:

```
if (age > 13) {
    System.out.println("You are eligible for this site, you may proceed. ");
} else {
 // End program here if statement = false
}
```

(Please answer with the code if you don't mind.)

Comment: use System.exit(0); in the else body. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (age > 13) {
    System.out.println("You are eligible for this site, you may proceed. ");
}else{
    System.exit(0); 
}
```

This should end it!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you have to add 0 in one of the arguments?

Comment: I don't know, why don't you try and change the value and see what happens! Nothing should change though  because it will always be its own constant variable.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. A Java program must never be stoped with System.exit.   It is akin to pulling the plug on your computer just to close Chrome. An application is closed when all the (non-daemon) threads it has started have ended and to close an application the programmer must ensure that this happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can exit your program with `System.exit()`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

if you on main just write return;

Answer (score 0):

if this is in main() method

just use `return`

if this is in another function return something back to the main like a `boolean` then `return`

Answer (score 0):

This will exit the JVM.

```
System.exit(-1); // or any other status
```

If this is the main method, you can also simply return from it (provided you haven't started a thread):

```
return;
```